# Compare the size of zip created using using java.util.zip to original folder size using java

Tags: java, zip

I have just created a Zip file using java.util.zip. Now I would want to check if the ZIP created is correct and the uncompressed size of the ZIP file is equal to the actual folders that I have zipped.

I know of a method ZipFile.isValid() which returns true if all the headers in the ZIP are correct. Doesn't solve my problem though.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to perform this check? Are you debugging, or would you use this code in production?

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the *.zip file, iterate over each ZipEntry element, sum each ZipEntry.getSize().  Compare this to the sum of the file sizes you zipped.  Alternatively (if you don't trust the ZipEntry headers for some reason) unzip each ZipEntry, counting the bytes, but discarding them.  You might do either of these things say, as a quick check of your zip code, or maybe even in a unit test.

You can iterate over the ZipEntry's thusly:

```
zipInStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
ZipEntry zipEntry;
while ((zipEntry = zipInStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
    String entryName = zipEntry.getName();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I thought of that. But he archives I am creating are really large. Don't want to unzip and iterate all over again!

Comment: Yeah, it seems silly doesn't it.  Yet that is the only way.  This probably explains why you haven't gotten many answers to this question.  :-)

Comment: Just unfortunate i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the ZIP file is created correctly

```
if (myZipFile.isValid())
{
    // The file has been created successfully
}
```

Knowing the Length of the directory and the file.

```
File dir = new File("path/to/the/directory/");
int size = dir.length();

File zip = new File("path/to/zipfile.zip");
int zipSize = zip.length();
```

Now you can compare them.

Comment: This compares the size of the *compressed* zip file to the size of just one directory in the zip file!  I don't think that is going to work.